# Retrieve Hierarchical Parent/Child Data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, hierarchical-data

In my Application, there is Therapeutic Area field, upon selection of it, user could select Disease followed by its 4 other Subtypes. All these 6 fields are multiselect, out of which only the 4 subtype fields are optional, the Therapeutic Area and Disease are mandatory. That means user may/may not select subtypes. If he selects, it could be of any level, not mandatory that it has to be all the 4.
The structure of Disease table is below.

```
ID  Name          DiseaseIdParent TherapeuticID DiseaseCode SubDisease1  SubDisease2  SubDisease3

1   DiseaseMain    NULL              1            M40          NULL         NULL         NULL
2   DiseaseSub1    1                 1            M40          NULL         NULL         NULL
3   DiseaseSub2    1                 1            M41           2           NULL         NULL
4   DiseaseSub3    1                 1            M42           2            3           NULL
5   DiseaseSub4    1                 1            M41           2            3            4
```

Below is what I have tried with Recursive CTE

```
;WITH DiseaseCTE AS 
       (
            SELECT
            hv.ID as hvId,th.Id as ThId,th.Name as ThName,ds.Id diseaseId,ds.Name as diseaseName
            ,CAST('0' as int) as diseaseId1,CAST('0' as varchar(1000)) as diseaseName1,CAST('0' as int) as diseaseId2
            ,CAST('0' as varchar(1000)) as diseaseName2
            ,CAST('0' as int) as diseaseId3,CAST('0' as varchar(1000)) as diseaseName3,CAST('0' as int) as diseaseId4,CAST('0' as varchar(1000)) as dsName4,ds.ICD_Code,CAST('0' as varchar(20)) as diseaseCode1,CAST('0' as varchar(20)) as diseaseCode2
            ,CAST('0' as varchar(20)) as diseaseCode3,CAST('0' as varchar(20)) as diseaseCode4

            FROM RecordTbl hv
            INNER JOIN RecordTherapeuticTbl ta on hv.Id=ta.RecordId
            INNER JOIN TherapeuticTbl th on th.ID=ta.TherapeuticId
            INNER JOIN DiseaseTbl ds on ds.TherapeuticIdID=th.ID
            INNER JOIN RecordPrimaryDisease pdhv on pdhv.RecordId=hv.ID and pdhv.Disease_Id=ds.Id and pdhv.RecordId in(2231,2232)

            WHERE hv.Id in(2231,2232)
            GROUP BY 
            hv.ID,th.Id,th.Name,ds.Id,ds.Name
            ,ds.DiseaseCode
              
            UNION ALL

            SELECT
            th.HvId as hvId ,th.ThId as ThId,th.ThName,th.diseaseId,th.dsName as diseaseName
            ,dss1.ID as diseaseId1,dss1.Name as diseaseName1,dss2.ID as diseaseId2,dss2.Name as diseaseName2
            ,dss3.ID as diseaseId3,dss3.Name as diseaseName3
            ,dss4.ID as diseaseId4,dss4.Name as diseaseName4
            ,th.ICD_Code as diseaseCode,dss1.DiseaseCode as diseaseCode1,dss2.DiseaseCode as diseaseCode2
            ,dss3.DiseaseCode as   diseaseCode3
            ,dss4.DiseaseCode as diseaseCode4
            FROM DiseaseCTE th 
            INNER JOIN DiseaseTbl dss1 on dss1.TherapeuticId=th.ThId and dss1.DiseaseIdParent=th.diseaseId
            INNER JOIN DiseaseTbl dss2 on dss2.TherapeuticId=th.ThId and dss2.SubDisease1=dss1.ID
            INNER JOIN DiseaseTbl dss3 on dss3.TherapeuticId=th.ThId and dss3.SubDisease2=dss2.ID
            INNER JOIN DiseaseTbl dss4 on dss4.TherapeuticId=th.ThId and dss4.SubDisease3=dss3.ID
            INNER JOIN RecordDiseaseSubtype sb1 on  sb1.DiseaseID=dss1.ID and sb1.RecordId  in(2231,2232)
            INNER JOIN RecordDiseaseSubtype2 sb2 on sb2.DiseaseID=dss2.ID and sb2.RecordId  in(2231,2232)
            INNER JOIN RecordDiseaseSubtype3 sb3 on sb3.DiseaseID=dss3.ID and sb3.RecordId  in(2231,2232)
            INNER JOIN RecordDiseaseSubtype4 sb4 on sb4.DiseaseID=dss4.ID and sb4.RecordId in(2231,2232)
            WHERE th.hvId in(2231,2232)
              
       )  


              select * from DiseaseCTE
                        GROUP BY 
              hvId,ThId,ThName,diseaseId,diseaseName
            ,diseaseId1, diseaseName1,diseaseId2, diseaseName2
            ,diseaseId3, diseaseName3
            ,diseaseId4,diseaseName4
            ,diseaseCode,diseaseCode1,diseaseCode2
            ,diseaseCode3
            ,diseaseCode4
```

Expected Output

```
+----------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| RecordId | TheraupeticId | TheraupeticName |       diseaseName       |    SubDisease1    |          SubDisease2          |           SubDisease3            |                SubDisease4                | DiseaseCode | SubDiseaseCode1 | SubDiseaseCode2 | SubDiseaseCode3 | SubDiseaseCode4 |
+----------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     2231 |            56 | Cardiovascular  | Coronary heart diseases | Coronary syndrome | Acute coronary syndrome (ACS) | ACS, acute myocardial infarction | ACS, acute myocardial infarction, type 2  | I24.9       | I24.9           | I24.9           | I21             | I21.9           |
|     2231 |            56 | Cardiovascular  | Coronary heart diseases | Coronary syndrome | Acute coronary syndrome (ACS) | ACS, acute myocardial infarction | ACS, acute myocardial infarction, type 4b | I24.9       | I24.9           | I24.9           | I21             | I21.9           |
|     2231 |            56 | Cardiovascular  | Coronary heart diseases | Coronary syndrome | Acute coronary syndrome (ACS) | ACS, acute myocardial infarction | ACS, acute myocardial infarction, type 5  | I24.9       | I24.9           | I24.9           | I21             | I21.9           |
|     2231 |            56 | Cardiovascular  | Coronary heart diseases | Coronary syndrome | Acute coronary syndrome (ACS) | ACS, myocardial infarction       | ACS, myocardial infarction, type 2        | I24.9       | I24.9           | I24.9           | I21             | I21             |
|     2231 |            56 | Cardiovascular  | Coronary heart diseases | Coronary syndrome | Acute coronary syndrome (ACS) | ACS, myocardial infarction       | ACS, myocardial infarction, type 4b       | I24.9       | I24.9           | I24.9           | I21             | I21             |
|     2231 |            56 | Cardiovascular  | Coronary heart diseases | Coronary syndrome | Acute coronary syndrome (ACS) | ACS, angina                      | ACS, stable angina                        | I24.9       | I24.9           | I24.9           | I20             | I20             |
|     2231 |            56 | Cardiovascular  | Coronary heart diseases | Coronary syndrome | Acute coronary syndrome (ACS) | ACS, angina                      | ACS, unstable angina                      | I24.9       | I24.9           | I24.9           | I20             | I20.9           |
|     2231 |            58 | Other           | Symptoms                | Dyspnea           | Respiratory dyspnea           | Respiratory distress/disease     | Acute respiratory distress/disease        | R10.2       | R06.0           | J80             | J80             | J80             |
+----------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+




You can see, there are 2 Theraupetics for this particular record 2231, SubDisease4 is the last branch. I want to fetch top 5 based on DiseaseCodes, here we will consider SubDiseaseCode4 because it is the last branch, and in this example the last branch is SubDisease4, for other records it might be Subdisease2 or SubDisease3 or might be none. Top 5 sets will be like for 
Eg: Set 1 would be till type 2
    Set 2 would be till type 4b
    .....Continues
```

You could see the branches it opens to. How to structure the data for multiple records, suppose something ends at DiseaseSubtype2 as the last branch, as inner join fails as per the logic I tried. Also, as mentioned what could be done for vast amount of records as we cant pass 25K under in operator.

The tables with prefix as "Record" in its name are transaction tables, with Diseases selected for the corresponding record Id. The problems what I am facing are:

1. As mentioned earlier subdiseases are not madatory and it may vary as per records. Some might have none or till 4 or till 2. Left Join never works for RecirsiveCTE. And in the Recursve part

```
th.HvId as hvId
```

throws below error
**The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion**.
I am getting the hierarchy if i fix it, but as you know even recordIds are vital. Since it returns the same Ids eg: 2231 for both parent and recursive part, this issue is occurring.

2. The in operator has many records inside it, as this is dynamic, this would go up to 25K(still increasing) and as I mentioned, not all Records will have subtypes being uniform and it may vary as per these records, with performance hindrance, and with also joins failing for some, as Subtype tables may not contain the recordIds.  Eg: 2231 might have still subtype1, 2232 will have till subtype3 and inner join fails there.

```
in(2231,2232)
```

This is many-many multiselect as depending on multiple Therapeutic, Diseases selected the branches only widen and I have to get best 5 combination among this based on DiseaseCode for each record.

Dynamic query is one thing i could remember, but running the loop for thousands of records might introduce performance problems.

I am here for a timely suggestion, would be helpful if provided one.

Thank you..

Comment: There is an option to overrule the default maxrecursion of 100 iterations, but some database redesign might be more appropriate. Table structures like `RecordDiseaseSubtype`, `RecordDiseaseSubtype2`, `RecordDiseaseSubtype3`, `RecordDiseaseSubtype4` and `Disease.SubDisease1`, `Disease.SubDisease2`, `Disease.SubDisease3` are flags for a redesign. And passing 25K _values_ to an `IN` operator does not look ideal either. This should be a table join with 25K _rows_.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Sander. But unfortunately, these are existing in Production, and might take some time for a redesign. Any approach you have amidst of all this? so that I could do something better on top of this.

Comment: Ignoring the database design, what is the purpose of this query? You explain why the query is not working, but not what you hope to get out of it (i.e. an overview with all diseases and the selected subdiseases?). Please provide some sample data besides the `Disease` table and the expected output.

Comment: Sander, I have made Edits with sample data as you insisted, please let me know if there is anything else you want me to mention.